# Resonance phenomena

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The original differential equation is

$$m\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}+a\frac{dx}{dt}+kx=F_1\cos\omega t$$

The differential equation for the amplitude of the steady state term is given by

$$f(w)=\frac{E_1}{\sqrt{(\lambda^2-\omega^2)^2+4b^2\omega^2}}$$

$$E_1=\frac{F_1}{m}$$

$$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$

$$2b=\frac{a}{m}$$

Differentiation and set $f'(w)=0$

$$0=4\omega(2b^2-(\lambda^2-\omega^2)^2$$

Notice that the zeroes of the equation is given by

$$w=0$$

$$\omega=\sqrt{\lambda^2-2b^2}$$

I have some confusion about the resonance of a system.

Resonance frequency
$$f=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}-\frac{a^2}{2m^2}}$$

Frequency of the corresponding free, damped oscillation is
$$f=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}-\frac{a^2}{4m^2}}$$

Can someone explain what makes this two so different!

When we solve for the external forces, we which $w$ we shall use? 
$$F(t)=\cos wt $$

Comment: Can you give us the differential equation, that we can check the details?

Comment: Okay. Give me sometime.

Comment: There are some typos in your question, sometimes you use $w$ and sometimes $\omega$.

Comment: There is no mathematical reason for the difference of resonance frequency. This is a phenomenon when there are external forces. I guess you will get a better answer in [physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You can also look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Sinusoidal_driving_force)